# How to use react-leaflet-pixi-overlay

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, pixi.js

Im trying to implement the minimal example of the [docs of react-leaflet-pixi-overlay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-leaflet-pixi-overlay). You can find the code below:

```
import React from "react";
import PixiOverlay from "react-leaflet-pixi-overlay";
import { Map, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const App = () => {
  const markers = [
    {
      id: "randomStringOrNumber",
      iconColor: "red",
      position: [-37.814, 144.96332],
      popup: renderToString(<div>All good!</div>),
      onClick: () => alert("marker clicked"),
      tooltip: "Hey!"
    },
    {
      id: "2",
      iconColor: "blue",
      position: [-37.814, 144.96332],
      popup: "Quack!",
      popupOpen: true, // if popup has to be open by default
      onClick: () => alert("marker clicked"),
      tooltip: "Nice!"
    }
  ];

  return (
    <Map
      preferCanvas={true}
      maxZoom={20}
      minZoom={3}
      center={[-37.814, 144.96332]}
      // Other map props...
    >
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <PixiOverlay markers={markers} />
    </Map>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I have implemented it in the following [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-newton-8el09), but doesnt work:

> _reactLeaflet.useLeaflet is not a function

Cant find any example on the internet.

Comment: The library does not seem to work for react-leaflet version 3.x but only for 2.x as it uses the latter.

Comment: Using 2.x throws following error `Cannot read property 'getContainer' of undefined`

Comment: Indeed. It does seem to work for both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made it work using following versions:

```
leaflet 1.3.4
react 16.14.0
react-dom 16.14.0
react-leaflet 2.8.0
react-leaflet-pixi-overlay 1.0.10
react-scripts 1.1.4
```

Check the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-voice-fwpvp) working